# ¿Cómo obtener el intervalo entre dos horas? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, schedule

Tengo dos horas, inicio y final, quiero recorrer ambas y mostrar un array con ngfor algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente obtengo la hora de inicio y la hora final de un objeto y lo formateo con momentJS:

```
   // Mapeo el objeto para obtener la hora de inicio y almaceno en variable start
    this.start = this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(initialTimeStr => initialTimeStr.initialTimeStr));
    console.log('start', this.start);
    //Mapeo el objeto para obtener la hora de inicio y almaceno en variable end
    this.end = this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(finalTimeStr => finalTimeStr.finalTimeStr) );
    console.log('end', this.end);
    //Formateo las horas
    let start = moment(this.start, "HH:mm");
    let end = moment(this.end, "HH:mm");
    //let diff = end.subtract(start);

    console.log('let start', start);
    console.log('let end', end);
    //intento obtener el rango
    let rangoHoras = momentRange.range(start, end);

    //rango start y end
    rangoHoras.start.format('HH:mm');
    rangoHoras.end.format('HH:mm');

    console.log('range start', start);
    console.log('range', rangoHoras);

    //  this.selectedPlace = this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.filter(schedule => schedule.place._id === this.addressID)
    console.log('hourEnd :>>', this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(finalTimeStr => finalTimeStr.finalTimeStr)));
    
    //Si ha seleccionado el lugar
    if(this.selectedPlace){
      console.log('hourStart :>>', this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(initialTimeStr => initialTimeStr.initialTimeStr)));
    }
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ¿Cómo obtengo de un array el rango de esta hora con una diferencia de una hora aplicando lib Moment JS?

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Answer (score 0):

Hay una librería que puedes usar para separar el rango que ya tienes en múltiples rangos donde tu especificas como se va a separar.

[moment-range-split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range-split)

En tu caso especifico, teniendo como base tu rango generado, solo lo pasas por la función split que te proporciona la librería, te deberá regresar un array de rangos donde cada uno contiene el inicio y fin de el periodo que necesitas.

```js
    const { range } = extendMoment(moment);
    const { split } = require("moment-range-split");

    var start = new Date(2021, 11, 8, 9);
    var end = new Date(2021, 11, 8, 13);


    let rangoHoras = range(start, end);
    console.log(rangoHoras);
    /*
    DateRange
      end: Moment
      start: Moment
    */
    var horas = split(rangoHoras, "hours");

    console.log(this.horas);
    /*    
        Array(4)
        0: DateRange {start: Moment, end: Moment}
        1: DateRange {start: Moment, end: Moment}
        2: DateRange {start: Moment, end: Moment}
        3: DateRange {start: Moment, end: Moment}
        length: 4
    */
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando en Angular.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-williams-9hyvw?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hola! Primeramente muchas gracias por responderme, enserio muchas gracias no sabes cuantas veces he intentado pero no lo logro, mira probe tu ejemplo pero me dice lo siguiente: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startOf') Te dejo el repo, tal vez le hechas un vistazo y tu encuentras más rapido el error, yo no pude: https://github.com/IzliaB/HTML-Booking/blob/main/select-date.component.ts

Comment: `this.start = new Date(2021, 11, 8, end);`, aquí yo solo puse una fecha genérica, ese es el constructor, mas bien a `this.start` asigna la fecha, pero lo traes de una variable `attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map`,  solo es cuestion de revisar el objeto y asegurar que en `this.start` tenga una fecha valida.